# Identifying this interesting shape, used on roof of building

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

I just noticed this roof beside the hotel I'm staying at. I'm assuming it is the result of a mathematical equation and that perhaps the geometrical shape even has a name.

If my assumption is correct, can anyone here help me identify the equation and/or name of the shape?

**Update:**

I'm intrigued since the shape is asymmetrical. See the lower left part in the image, where the roof bends outwards and then falls sharply down towards the right.

[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell from the image.  Is it just a section of some type of [ellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid)?  Or a [prolate spheroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spheroid) (or possibly even an oblate spheroid)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I was a bit intrigued by asymmetry in the lower left part in the image, where the roof bends outwards and then falls sharply down towards the right. I'm really a fish out of water here, but wouldn't your suggestions imply a symmetrical shape?

Comment: Oh, and I'll see if I can possibly get an image from another angle here, but not sure if I can.

Comment: Not only the very edge itself. Part of the actual roof also bends outwards there.